# Locomotive scroll sticky header

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling, locomotive-scroll

I found this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/limedon/pen/wvobMQO)  using locomotive scroll and implementing sticky header.

Once I click and drag the smooth scrollbar, the sticky header stops working . What could be the reason ?

```html
let options = {
el: document.querySelector('#js-scroll'),
smooth: true,
getSpeed: true,
getDirection: true,
reloadOnContextChange:true
}
const header = document.getElementById('header');
let hidden = false,static = true;

const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll(options);

scroll.on('scroll',(instance)=>{
let headerHeight = header.getBoundingClientRect().height;
if(instance.direction === 'down' && static){
  if(instance.scroll.y > headerHeight){
  header.classList.add('pinned');
  static = false;
  }
}
if(instance.direction === 'up' && !static){
  if(instance.scroll.y <= headerHeight){
  header.classList.remove('pinned');
    static = true;
  }
}
if(instance.direction === 'down' && !hidden){
  if(instance.scroll.y>(headerHeight+200)){
  //console.log('hidden');
  header.classList.remove('pinned');
  header.classList.add('unpinned');
  hidden = true;
  }
}
if(instance.direction === 'up' && hidden){
  //console.log('show');
  header.classList.remove('unpinned');
  header.classList.add('pinned');
  hidden = false;
}
});
```

https://codepen.io/limedon/pen/wvobMQO

#### Edit -----------

On clicking and dragging, `instance.direction` changes to "left/right" instead of "up/down".

Answer (score 0):

When you grab the scrollbar it adds the class 'has-scroll-dragging' to the html.. try adding this before the closing }); in your code above.

```
if($("html").hasClass("has-scroll-dragging")){
header.classList.remove('unpinned');
header.classList.add('pinned');
hidden = false;
}
```